# I am trying to read in multiple files from a directory and use them in my program before moving on to other files in the directory

Tags: c++, unix

I have a directory with 188 files in it that look something like this.

```
001_AU01_query.dat  
001_AU12_query.dat  
001_AU17_query.dat    
001_template.dat  
002_AU01_query.dat  
002_AU12_query.dat  
002_AU17_query.dat  
002_template.dat
```

This repeats all the way to 047_AU
What my program needs to do is take in one query file and the corresponding template file i.e.(use the 001_AU01_query.dat with the 001_template.dat file) and run through the code. Then use the next 001_AU file with the same template file. This will repeat all the way to 047.

I can manually put in one query file and one template file and it works fine. I just do not know how to go about using all files in the directory.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      string outFileName = "";
      string templateFile = "";
      string queryData = "";
      ofstream outStream;

      Scanner inStreamTemp;
      Scanner inStreamQuery;

      calc calc;

      Utils::CheckArgs(3, argc, argv, "queryData templateFile outFileName");
      queryData = "data_project_part1/001_AU01_query.dat";   
      templateFile = "data_project_part1/001_template.dat";
      outFileName = "outFile";

      Utils::FileOpen(outStream, outFileName);

      if (Utils::FileDoesNotExist(queryData)||Utils::FileDoesNotExist(templateFile))
      {
        cout << "ERROR: query data file or template file name does not exist" << endl;
        exit(0);
      }

      inStreamQuery.openFile(queryData);
      inStreamTemp.openFile(templateFile);

      calc.initialize(inStreamQuery, inStreamTemp); 
      calc.runComputation(outStream);


      outStream << "Query File: " << queryData << "\n" << "Template File: " << templateFile << "\n" << "The ten closests neighbors are:\n" << calc.toStringResults() << "\n" << endl;
      outStream.flush();

      Utils::FileClose(outStream);

      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to put your file names in a list and loop through that list. 
You can put those names in a list by copying and pasting them to a text editor, save in notepad, read line by line and add to a list .

Then loop through that list and read from each one using a foreach loop